# search page number - Google custom search API

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, google-custom-search

I m using Google custom search API to fetch some images. Everything is working fine but all my queries result in the same result. Can i use some kind of page number of the starting point of my search or something else to get different images for the same keyword. (eg. "plane").

Here is my code,

```
async function imgRequest(options, arrayImg) {
    const res = await customsearch.cse.list({
        cx: "-----",
        q: "plane",
        auth: "-----",
        searchType: "image"
    });
    console.log(res.data.items[0].link);
    return res.data;
}
```

Thanks in advance. Feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 'start' parameter: "The index of the first result to return"

See
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list